# A Trace/breakpoint trap problem occurred when programming in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct StackB
{
    int Top;
    float Arr[30+10];
}*Stack;

Stack MakeEmpty(int Capacity);
void Clear(char *Str, int Len);
void Push(Stack S, float X);
float Pop(Stack S);

int main()
{
    int i, j, First, Len, ELen;
    const float MAX=1000000000000000000000000000000.0;
    float Ans;
    double Res, Div1, Div2;
    char Str[30], Temp[30];
    bool F;
    F=true;
    struct Obj
    {
        char Opr;
        float Num;
    }Expr[30];
    Stack S;
    S=MakeEmpty(30);
    for (i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        Expr[i].Num=MAX;
        Expr[i].Opr='!';
    }
    gets(Str);
    Len=strlen(Str);
    for (i=0;i<Len;i++)
        if (Str[i]==' ')
            Str[i]='\0';
    i=0;
    j=0;
    Clear(Temp, Len);
    while (i<Len)
    {
        First=i;
        while (Str[i]!='\0')
        {
            Temp[i-First]=Str[i];
            i++;
        }
        if (Temp[1]=='\0'&&(Temp[0]<'0'||Temp[0]>'9'))
        {
            Expr[j].Opr=Temp[0];
        }
        else
        {
            Res=atof(Temp);
            Expr[j].Num=(float)Res;
        }
        i++;
        j++;
        Clear(Temp, Len);
    }
    ELen=--j;
    for (i=ELen;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if (Expr[i].Opr=='!')
            Push(S, Expr[i].Num);
        else if (Expr[i].Num==MAX)
        {
            switch (Expr[i].Opr)
            {
                case '+':
                    Push(S, Pop(S)+Pop(S));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    Push(S, Pop(S)-Pop(S));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    Push(S, Pop(S)*Pop(S));
                    break;
                case '/':
                {
                    Div1=Pop(S);
                    Div2=Pop(S);
                    if (Div2==0)
                        F=false;
                    else
                        Push(S, Div1/Div2);
                }
                    break;
            }
            if (!F)
                break;
        }
    }
    if (F)
    {
        free(S);
        Ans=Pop(S);
        printf("%.1f", Ans);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        free(S);
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
}

void Clear(char *Str, int Len)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<Len;i++)
        Str[i]='\0';
}

void Push(Stack S, float X)
{
    S->Arr[++S->Top]=X;
}

float Pop(Stack S)
{
    float Temp;
    Temp=S->Arr[S->Top];
    S->Arr[S->Top--]=0;
    return Temp;
}

Stack MakeEmpty(int Capacity)
{
    int i;
    Stack S;
    S=(Stack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    S->Top=-1;
    for (i=0;i<Capacity;i++)
        S->Arr[i]=0;
    return S;
}
```

I have been working on a dsa problem, after running the GDB a few times with breakpoints in between, an exception named trace/breakpoint trap occurred. The VS-code indicated that the problem happened on this line:

```
free(S);
```

I have been hinted elsewhere that this has something to do with releasing memory at the end of a program, but even when I tried to free the Stack, the same thing happens.

Comment: type `Stack` is defined as a pointer to `struct StackB`. `sizeof(Stack)` is thus the size of a single pointer. If you start writing into its `Arr` member, there is a very real possibility that you are screwing up other memory allocations. You want at least `sizeof(*Stack)` or somesuch.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: As pointed out by @Botje, you are only allocating the size of a pointer in `malloc`, therefore you are probably corrupting the heap by writing beyond this allocated buffer. This heap corruption is probably detected when you call the function `free`, so it triggers an exception. EDIT: It seems that someone else discovered another problem in your code and wrote an answer about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Botje, I have corrected it to sizeof(*Stack), but same thing bumped up again...

Comment: Thanks, @dbush, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct StackB
{
    int Top;
    float Arr[30+10];
}*Stack; // Maybe you mean Stack ? 
/* .. 
   code
   ..  
*/
if (F)
{
    free(S); // Use after free
    Ans=Pop(S); // <----
    // Ans=Pop(S); free(S); that is the correct order
    // Pop(S) is writing to an offset of S + something, so i think it writes on some critical data that the free() function left behind
    printf("%.1f", Ans);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    free(S);
    printf("ERROR");
    return 0;
}
```

I think that is the problem

https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals#Free_Algorithm

Also, you are defining your struct as a pointer to a struct by default, so it never is really on the stack, and you need to allocate some memory for it on the heap

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the order, but sadly the problem still occurred.

Comment: As @Botje commented, I tried to do sizeof(*Stack), but the IDE simply wouldn't run. Should I perhaps define it as something else?

Comment: Oh now i noticed that you call gets(Str) and not gets(&Str), try that. Also, try to hardcore the size of your struct to the malloc and test if the problem happen again

Comment: It seem that function requires only one pointer argument. The IDE says "cannot convert 'char (*)[30]' to 'char*'".

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but I actually don't know what "hardcore the size" means(laugh). I am only a freshman in CS.

Comment: if you call gets(Str) , then you say to the gets function to write the input from the user to Str[0], not at the address of Str. This is why you say &Str, or the address of Str. Also , try to reset your code to its first state ( before you correct anything ) and take some screenshots of the errors from the IDE, and upload them to your question. Also, what IDE are you using?

Comment: I mean type S = malloc ( sizeof( float * ( 30 + 10 ) ) + sizeof( int ) ) . And i meant hardcode, sorry about the typo

Comment: I use VS-code, and it has objected to all of your suggestions so far(signs~). For the hardcode one, it has noted something like "expected ')' before numeric constant".

Comment: type S = malloc ( sizeof( float ) * ( 30 + 10 ) + sizeof( int ) );

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens...(signs~)

Comment: could you provide more info about the problem, like what OS, output of the program, output of the debugger, anything useful

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved. What I did was typing `S=(Stack)malloc(sizeof(float)*30+sizeof(int))`.

Comment: At least do `sizeof(struct StackB)` instead, then, because your struct has space for 40 floats, not 30